# Why am I getting these white lines on my model?

Tags: modeling

Why am I getting these white lines along the side of my model?

[image]

What is the root cause and how can I fix it?

Comment: Are you in *Edit Mode*? Those look like selected edges but in white instead orange.. feel free to share the blend file at https://blend-exchange.com

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you have Cavity turned on in the viewport shading properties.
[image]

You should start another question about improving the topology. But here you go:

As a rule of thumb, the topology should be more equalized. For instance, the topology in y-axis towards the front of the model looks nicely distributed, but towards the back it doesn't. It is very hard to judge the whole model without the model tho.
The very front faces of the model will cause some trouble with bevels and such (overlapping), so the inner vertices should get a better distribution. Again, very hard to describe without the model.